# How to restrict write access to users which are declared under a specific node in the Real Time Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I noticed something weird in my app. First of all, I register.

[image]

And then go in the welcome screen.

[image]

And to verify that I am indeed registered in firebase I go in the console. First in Authentication

[image]

And then in Database where you see a node called Users(I declared as Users when I was registering).

[image]

But let's say that I accidentally delete this user from the db. The user is still logged in the app and tries to comment on an article. Obviously, there is going to be a response,

```
E/CommentActivity: User AhtNY3bm7aQdPiJewf3PBN310732 is unexpectedly null
```

And this comes from here.

```
User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

                    // [START_EXCLUDE]
                    if (user == null) {
                        // User is null, error out
                        Log.e(TAG, "User " + userId + " is unexpectedly null");
                        Toast.makeText(CommentActivity.this,
                                "Error: could not fetch user.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
```

The whole code of the CommentActivity is [here](https://github.com/theo82/Capstone-Udacity/blob/master/app/src/main/java/theo/tziomakas/news/CommentActivity.java).

Is there any way to avoid that kind of error? I mean once the user is registered in firebase, he can post comments even if he is accidentally deleted. Maybe use any of setter/getter methods from here?

```
public class User {

public String username;
public String email;


public User() {
    // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(User.class)
}

public User(String username, String email) {
    this.username = username;
    this.email = email;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

}
```

**UPDATE**

I put this rules

```
{
  "rules": {
  ".read": "auth != null",
  ".write": "auth != null"
},
{
  "rules": {
  "comments": {
  ".write": "auth != null && root.child('Users').hasChild(auth.uid)"
  ".read": "auth != null"
  }
 }
 }  
}
```

but I get a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no automatic link between the existence of your user in the Authentication panel and the user's data under the `Users` node, in your DB. So, like you mention in your post, if you delete the `user` node in the DB, he/she will still be able to authenticate.

Therefore you have to secure your database with a dedicated **security rule** (Consider it as the *authorization* part of the whole *authentication/authorization* mechanism).

You should write this database security rule in such a way that the user's UID must exist under the `Users` node to allow him/her to write a "comment", as follows:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "comments": {
      ".write": "auth != null && root.child('Users').hasChild(auth.uid)"
      ".read": ...
    }
  }
}
```

Here, we make the assumption that the `comments` node is directly under the database root. It is up to you to adapt this rule to your data model (and probably includes the post UID in this path).

Have a look at the corresponding documentation on Security, [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security), and in particular the full example at the end of the doc.

Comment: Can you please see my updated question? I get a syntax error.

Comment: You should not have two "rules" blocks. If you just want to secure the comments node, delete the first "rules" block. But I guess that you need to secure others parts of your database. I would kindly suggest that you thoroughly study the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/